# How to concatenate all occurrences of a Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns of data and one other column which contains the search key. I am trying to fetch all results that contain a specific text which I'm able to do. The challenge is that I need to concatenate all the occurrences into one single cell.

I have tried the following formula:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2:F,B:C,2,FALSE),""))`

Which works but halfway through. So what remains is fetching all the other results into one cell. Currently, it's only fetching a single result.

[image]

In this image, the desired output is in F2 for the search key Paul in E2.

Link to my spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GujlPIn3sqh4DX-taG5b65futHBJrgi6rNmj5zNmdM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=JOIN(,FILTER(B:B, A:A=E2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there an arrayformula for this? If I have several search keys in column E?

Comment: @DanstanOngubo yes, see your sheet

Comment: Since I got lots of data, the first accepted drag down formula seems to favor speed. The only challenge I'm facing is manipulating the formula so that is begins the search from the bottom. I'm attempting with the SORT function but I can't quite get it to work. Illustrated in my earlier spreadsheet.

Comment: you can do: `=JOIN(, INDEX(SORT(FILTER({C:C, ROW(A:A)}, B:B=F2), 2, 0),,1))`